# Swift 3: Restrict .components array and use reduce

Tags: arrays, swift, file, components, reduce

I try to get the first n parts of a path:

```
var rootPath = "/p1/p2"
var filePath = "/p1/p2/p3/p4/file.ext"
```

I want to get one more than used by `rootPath = 3` folders deep:

```
result = "/p1/p2/p3/"
```

I try to use build-in array components, but I don't know how to restrict it to a specific number:

```
func getRootFolderRel(rootURL : URL, fileURL : URL, relIndex : Int) -> String {
    let pccount = rootURL.pathComponents.count + 1

    var count = 0
    return fileURL.pathComponents.reduce("", { count += 1 < pccount ? $0.stringByAppendingPathComponent(pathComponent: $1) : $0 })
}
```

Any hints? (It should be as fast as possible) :-)

Added: (I wrote an working function, but it is not using internal commands. Everything is done by me, so I assume, it is very slow compared to solutions based on build-in functions).

```
func getRootFolderRel(rootURL : URL, fileURL : URL, relIndex : Int) -> String {
    let pccount = rootURL.pathComponents.count + relIndex

    var array = [String]()
    var count = 0
    while count < pccount && count < rootURL.pathComponents.count {
        array.append(rootURL.pathComponents[count])
        count += 1
    }

    let offset = count
    while count < pccount && count < fileURL.pathComponents.count {
        array.append(fileURL.pathComponents[count])
        count += 1
    }

    return array.reduce("", { $0.stringByAppendingPathComponent($1) })
}
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear `rootPath` is a `String` on one line and then an `Int` next.. Are your paths always in the format `/p1/p2/.../pn/file.txt` and you want to stop at index `i`? Or you want to stop at the i-th level depth, i.e. `/path/to/my/text/file.txt` with `i = 2` -> `/path/to`?

Comment: I want to stop at the relative position index to rootURL. -1 means result is "/p1", +1 means "/p1/p2/p3", +1 means "/p1/p2/p3/p4". So base is rootURL, index indicades number of additional or missing subfolders.